# Limit $ \sum_{k=0}^∞ \left( \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j} \left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^j \right) $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have to find the limit of the following series:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^∞ \left( \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j} \left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^j \right) $$

I don't even know how to approach this... Any help would be very appreciated

Comment: How would you define ${k\choose j}$ with $j>k$? and if the second sum is supposed to go from $j=0$ to $k$, do you know the binomial formula?

Comment: Ohhh ok that was my own mistake, for the second sum sign there has to be a k on top... I'll fix it

Comment: You do not want the limit - you want the value of the sum. There is no variable that you can take the limit with respect to, unless you mean the upper value of the outer sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the binomial formula and the geometric series formula:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{k}{k\choose j}\left(-\frac13\right)^j\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac13\right)^k=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{(2/3)^{k+1}-1}{(2/3)-1}=\frac1{1-(2/3)}=3$$

Comment: Thank you, that explains it!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The inner sum is just$$\sum_{j=0}^k\binom kj\left(-\frac13\right)^j=\left(1-\frac13\right)^k.$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that according to the Newton's binomial theorem, $$ \sum_{j=0}^∞ \binom{k}{j} (x)^j =(1+x)^k$$

For $x= (-1/3)$ we get $$ \sum_{j=0}^∞ \binom{k}{j} (x)^j =(1+x)^k= (2/3)^k$$

Thus we have $$\sum_{k=0}^∞ \left( \sum_{j=0}^∞ \binom{k}{j} \left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^j \right)= \frac {1}{1-2/3} =3$$

Answer (score 0):

Since,
by the binomial theoram,
$ \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}x^j 
=(1+x)^k
$,

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=0}^∞ \left( \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}x^j \right)
&=\sum_{k=0}^∞ (1+x)^k\\
&=\dfrac{1}{1-(1+x)}
\qquad\text{geometric series with ratio }1+x\\
&=\dfrac{-1}{x}\\
\end{array}
$

Putting $x=-\frac13$,
this gives
$\dfrac{-1}{-\frac13}
=3$.

Note that the sum
does not converge
if $x > 0$,
or else you would
get the nonsensical result
(if, say,
$x=\frac12$),
$\sum_{k=0}^∞ \left( \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}(1/2)^j \right)
=-2$.